# text format in HTML5

Tags: html

When I enter into my tag `h1` a phrase.

For example, I write a phrase in french -> `Nous découvrir en vidéo`

```
<h1 class="primaryTitle"> Nous découvrir en vidéo </h1>
```

In the display, I get this message

```
Nous dÃ©couvrir en vidÃ©o
```

I don't understand where comes the problem ?

I think, the problem is perhaps here ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<head>
<title>title</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="icon" href="../favicon.gif" >
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Encoding for French characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309183/html-encoding-for-french-characters)

Comment: @Martin Meli: Sorry Martin, it's ok now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="primaryTitle"> Nous découvrir en vidéo </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

English

```
<html lang="en">
```

French

```
<html lang="fr">
```

Comment: Specifying the language the document is written in, while a good thing to do generally, won't help solve character encoding problems.

Comment: The charset was also set to UTF-8. Both in combination are a good idea.

Comment: **Guessing** at the character encoding isn't a great idea either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Nous découvrir en vidéo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Change the charset in the meta tag to "UTF-8", this worked when i tried it